# Keystorne authentication

Tags: keystone

I'm want use as a external storage the Openstack swift on Owncloud, but I don't know if I it is right. So, please, tell me: Could I use the Openstack Swift + Keystone auth method on Owncloud? I'm using Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

If, what you are trying to do is use the same authentication you already have in place for owncloud and have it work for swift, you should be able to create a keystone plugin to handle the authentication.
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/ClientAuthenticationPlugin.
If you wrote a plugin so that keystone authentication was effectively delegated to the owncloud authentication then accessing swift could be based on the same credentials.

If what you mean is, you want owncloud to provide swift api to an open stack cloud, that would require something different.